# Gradle - could not find method runtime(), but I don't have it in my project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to gradle, and having some difficulties when migrating project from gradle 6.8.1 to 7.0.2. Here is mine build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.generali.gef.gradle:gef-ws-xsd-starter-plugin:$GEF_VERSION"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'gef-ws-xsd-starter-plugin'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.generali.gef:gef-ws-xsd',
            'gef-ws-xsd-starter-plugin'
}
```

In gradle 6.8.1, it all worked just fine. However, when I changed the version to 7.0.2, this script started throwing this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':demo-ws-xsd'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'gef-ws-xsd-starter-plugin'.
   > Could not find method runtime() for arguments [org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I know that *runtime* keyword was removed in gradle 7, however this keyword is not anywhere in my .gradle files. Any ideas what could be wrong?

**edit**

it is thrown by line 8 of the file, meaning

```
apply plugin: 'gef-ws-xsd-starter-plugin'
```